Error with './gradlew assembleRelease': Failed to install Android SDK packages due to unaccepted licenses
Background:
I'm encountering an issue while trying to build a release version of my Android application using './gradlew assembleRelease'. I've already accepted all Android SDK licenses using the command sdkmanager --licenses, and it confirms that all licenses are accepted.
Issue:
However, I continue to receive the following error:
Despite re-accepting the licenses multiple times, the error persists.
Error Message:
PS D:\documents\vscode\nodejs\start-sphere\android> ./gradlew assembleRelease
...

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-asset (10.0.10)
  - expo-constants (16.0.2)
  - expo-file-system (17.0.1)
  - expo-font (12.0.8)
  - expo-keep-awake (13.0.2)
  - expo-modules-core (1.12.19)
  - expo-speech (12.0.2)

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in C:\Program Files\Android\SDK\cmdline-tools\tools\bin\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 34 in C:\Program Files\Android\SDK\cmdline-tools\tools\bin\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 34 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     platforms;android-34 Android SDK Platform 34
     build-tools;34.0.0 Android SDK Build-Tools 34
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  All licenses can be accepted using the sdkmanager command line tool:
  sdkmanager --licenses
  Or, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

  Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\SDK\cmdline-tools\tools\bin

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 11s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Attempts:
I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

Re-running sdkmanager --licenses.
Ensuring that the SDK paths are correctly configured in my environment.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project.


You can use yes | in front of that command to auto accept the licence. Incase you are running on CLI.
Correct command to accept licence is this:
yes | sdkmanager --licenses

For build tool specific it will be:
echo yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;34.0.0"

Also can you share the steps to accept licence from android studio.
Read this post for more information:

https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager#accept-licenses


I hope one of the links can help you with your question.

"Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error
: "Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted" error

How to Fix “Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licenses have not been accepted” Error in Android Studio? : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licenses-have-not-been-accepted-error-in-android-studio/

Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted : https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/3687


